# Android: How to use PosAtTime with a date

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I need execute an action on a specific date

```
   Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postAtTime({
            texto.text = "Testo ha cambiado"
        },2020-02-12)
```

Comment: the `updateTimeMillis` should be a long data type, given `SystemClock.uptimeMillis() + 10000` will be invoked at 10s later

Comment: based on the documentation https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler#postAtTime(java.lang.Runnable,%20long)

Comment: Can I put a date on this? Can you give me an example? or do you know a way to do it that I need... Please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`postAtTime` takes a milliseconds value. You'll need to use some date library (like [`Date`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Date)) to create an object representing the date you want. Then use its "convert to milliseconds / Unix time" method (for `Date` it's [`getTime()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Date#getTime())) to get a value you can pass to `postAtTime`

But if you post a message to the `Handler`, your app will need to stay running *the whole time* until the time your message is handled. If the app is closed (including by the system) that message is gone. And your app needs to be running in the foreground when it happens too. It's not meant for scheduling important events that have to happen even if the app is closed, and it's *really* not meant for things way off in the future

You probably want to use [`AlarmManager`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager)

> Note: The Alarm Manager is intended for **cases where you want to have your application code run at a specific time, even if your application is not currently running**. For normal timing operations (ticks, timeouts, etc) it is easier and much more efficient to use Handler.

(there's also [`WorkManager`](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/) which isn't about a specific *time* but might be better for whatever you're doing)